# Customizing WooCommerce category page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have spent the majority of the day trying to figure out how to add a simple "Join Us" button at the bottom of a page on my WordPress site. This page is a category page handled using the WooCommerce plugin. I did my research and found that I have to edit the content-product.php file within the WooCommerce plugin. 
I copied the file to my theme folder and tried to edit it, but it is adding two buttons at random places instead of one.

This is the page I want to add the button to:
https://www.wagingpeace.org/product-category/cards-for-humanity/

Is content-product.php the file that I have to edit? Is this something related to the function.php file?
Any kind of help is heartily appreciated.

Comment: I would really like to help you but I had a look at your page and don't understand some things. Can you edit your question and provide the version of WooCommerce you are using and a list of other plugins you are using and the theme you are using.

Comment: Ah, I understand why things look so different. You are using WooCommerce   2.6.8 and the current version is 3.1.0. Since, this will be a lot of work for me to install this old version please let me know if you are still looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: I didn't look at your page carefully enough and didn't notice the shop items were at the bottom of the page. I think the solution below by ashvek should solve your problem. I like the cause of this website and if that solution doesn't work or if you need any other technical assistance you can contact me at http://tml.magentacuda.com/contact-me/

Answer (score 0):

content-product.php is used to display content of each product in a archive. Since there are 2 products in the category, button is shown twice.
add this to themes functions.php:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'custom_join_us', 10, 0);
function custom_join_us() {
// Button code here
}
```

Comment: add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'custom_join_us', 10, 0);
function custom_join_us() {
echo "<button><a href ="https://www.wagingpeace.org/join/">Join Us</a></button>";
} Is this okay?

Comment: You dont have to put <a> tag inside <button> tag. <a> tag can be styled like a button.

Use this instead and style the 'button' class:
echo '<a href="wagingpeace.org/join/" class="button">Join Us</a>';

Comment: So basically, adding custom css to the button class? Does that css go in the  website's stylesheet?Also, I added the above code, and the whole website crashed. I know I should be using a child theme, but I don't have the installation files. Any other way?

Comment: add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'custom_join_us', 10, 0);
function custom_join_us() {
?>
<a href="https://www.wagingpeace.org/join/" style="
    background-color: #ff5f51;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 120px;
    text-decoration: none;
">Join Us</a>
<?php
}

Comment: Copy paste above code in functions.php. If it works please up vote my answer and also mark correct.